# how to add child view exact below its parent firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is how my database structure looks like:
[image: database]

I am creating chat app with the use of Firebase in android.

This below code is for chat message

```
 SnapshotParser<GroupMessage> parser = new 
   SnapshotParser<GroupMessage>() {
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public GroupMessage parseSnapshot(final 
    DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            final GroupMessage groupMessage = 
          dataSnapshot.getValue(GroupMessage.class);

            if (groupMessage != null) {


                groupMessage.setId(dataSnapshot.getKey());

            }

            return groupMessage;
        }
    };
```

Here, both message and reply data are in different model class(GroupMessage & MessageReplyModel), now I want to display message and reply like Facebook has.

```
  mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child
   (Constants.MESSAGE_REPLIES).getRef()
   .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                MessageReplyModel replyModel = dataSnapshot1.getValue(MessageReplyModel.class);

                replyModel.setId(dataSnapshot.getKey());

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

How can I show reply of particular message below that message.

In my firebase structure, I also have message id for particular message on which reply will is performed.

So how can I do that ?

Comment: Do you want I'd of your parent msg ?

Comment: Show us your database structure and please responde with @.

Comment: You should add parameters in GroupMessge class why are you creating new java pojo object... It will be difficult to maintain the reply msg identity. Isn't it ?

Comment: i have parent msg id @PradeepDeshmukh

Comment: I think you should use two different queries, one for the main messages and another for loading the replays if exists. In the database you should store a list where new replies are pushed, ordered by date in this case.

Comment: i put my firebase database structure @AlexMamo

Comment: can  u please help me with some code @Juanje

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should split the requests in two different queries: the first one to handle the main thread of messages; and a different one to handle the replies to each main message.

**READ:**

```
databaseReference.child("MAIN_THREAD").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            // HANDLE DATA AND CHECK IF HAS REPLIES

            if (dataSnapshot.getValue().getReplies() != null && dataSnapshot.getValue().getReplies().size() != 0){
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("REPLIES_THREAD").orderByChild("PARENT_MESSAGE").equalTo("PARENT_UID")
                        .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        //HANDLE REPLIES
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        }

        ......
    });
```

**WRITE:**

```
    databaseReference.child("MAIN_THREAD").push().setValue(new Message());

    databaseReference.child("REPLIES_THREAD").push().setValue(new Message());
    databaseReference.child("MAIN_THREAD").child("PARENT_MESSAGE").child("replies").push().setValue("MESSAGE_UID");
```

Code should follow this structure. Note that is not the full code and I put names that you must adapt to the code and classes that you are using.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @Juanje but i dont't to how to handle those replies, how can i show them below particular messages, i have list of replies into my new replyModel class, so can you please tell me that how can i handle those replies...@Juanje

Comment: @BhaveshMakwana each item of the main list, needs a `ListView` or a `RecyclerView` to load these replies I told you. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck with the rest of your app! @BhaveshMakwana